# Read array from PDO using FETCH_KEY_PAIR

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am trying to read the array from the following code. I thought it should be easy but I am struggling.

My code pulls back two variables in the array.

```
$stmt5=$mysql_link->prepare("SELECT stationlong AS stationlong,tpl AS tpl FROM station WHERE stationlong=:stationlong LIMIT 1");
$stmt5->execute(array(':stationlong'=>$q));
$stations=$stmt5->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
var_dump($stations);
$stationlongs=$stations[0];
$stationshorts=$stations[1];
```

An example array is as follows:-

```
array(1) {["Leicester"]=>string(6) "LESTER"}
```

My error is NOTICE: undefined offset: 0 in........... for $stationlongs=$stations[0]; and the same again for $stationshorts but with offset 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key `0` doesn't exist. As you see in dump, you have one record. There are no keys `0` and `1` in your one-item array.

```
echo $stations['Leicester']; // returns LESTER
```